Understanding Deduplication Mechanism in ClickHouse ReplicatedMergeTree
I have a ReplicatedMergeTree ClickHouse table, and I want to understand how the deduplication mechanism works. The parameters: replicated_deduplication_window_seconds and non_replicated_deduplication_window are set to their defaults: 1 week and 100 records, respectively.
From the documentation, I read that row uniqueness is achieved by calculating block_id, which is a hash-summ of the entire batch. However, when executing queries with different batches but overlapping data sets, it seems to me that uniqueness is being checked on a row-by-row basis.
For example:
INSERT INTO traffic_2_test (event_date, page_url)
VALUES ('2024-02-01', 'url.test'),
       ('2024-02-02', 'url.test');

INSERT INTO traffic_2_test (event_date, page_url)
VALUES ('2024-02-01', 'url.test'),
       ('2024-02-02', 'url.test'),
       ('2024-02-03', 'url.test');

INSERT INTO traffic_2_test (event_date, page_url)
VALUES ('2024-02-03', 'url.test');

These three queries add 3 rows to the table instead of 6, even though the batches are different.
Why does this happen? It seems that deduplication based on individual rows rather than the entire batch hash.
From the documentation:

When data is inserted into ClickHouse, it is split data into blocks based on the number of rows and bytes.


For tables using *MergeTree engines, each block is assigned a unique block_id, which is a hash of the data in that block. This block_id is used as a unique key for the insert operation. If the same block_id is found in the deduplication log, the block is considered a duplicate and is not inserted into the table.


What table engine are you using?

@RichRaposa ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/prod/traffic_2_test', '{replica}')

I could not reproduce - https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/5a2ab964-e877-4a5c-982a-c23b9041fdf3
Could try to reproduce it and share the steps?

Deduplication worked as intended. However, since the table was partitioned by the event_date field, the original batch was split into smaller batches for each partition under the hood. Thus the hash that used by the deduplication mechanism was computed separately for each of these partitioned batches.
